# TypeScript decorators phenomenon (decorator parameter becomes undefined in a special case)

Tags: typescript, decorator

i am trying to implement my own ORM and i have found something interesting in TypeScript, what i don't understand. Maybe one of you can explain it to me, or maybe its a typescript bug.

Here is the simplified basic structure, where this phenomenon also is there.

We have a property decorator, which takes one parameter of type of a class.

```
// This is not required, only used to define the entityClass type more explicite
export abstract class Entity { }


export function Decorator(entityClass: typeof Entity) {
    return function(target: any, propertyName: string) {
        console.log(entityClass);
    }
}
```

A file with Class A:
EntityA.ts

```
import { Entity, Decorator } from "./index";
import { EntityB } from "./EntityB";

export class EntityA extends Entity {

    @Decorator(EntityB)
    public propertyA: any;
}
```

A file with Class B:
EntityB.ts

```
import { Entity, Decorator } from "./index";
import { EntityA } from "./EntityA";

export class EntityB extends Entity {

    @Decorator(EntityA)
    public propertyB: any;
}
```

A little bit code to trigger typescript to use the decorator to output the console.log:

run.ts

```
import { EntityA } from "./EntityA";
import { EntityB } from "./EntityB";


const objA = new EntityA();
const objB = new EntityB();
```

On run this script i get:

```
undefined
[Function: EntityB]
```

This `undefined` is this phenomenon.
Now i delete in EntityA.ts this line `@Decorator(EntityB)` and run the script again, and the `undefine` is gone. Instead i get the expected output:

```
[Function: EntityA]
```

Did i missunderstood something about decorators or is this a typescript bug?

Answer (score 1):

You have circular references in the code - `EntityA` depends on `EntityB` and vice versa.

During initialization of `EntityA`, `EntityB` passed into `@Decorator(EntityB)` is `undefined`, so decorator captures 'undefined` value.

During initialization of `EntityB`, `EntityA` already exists, so everything seems to work fine.